# Can the execution point of a Java application be modified or specified while debugging under Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio IDE (v1.5.1) and its Gradle debugger to step thru my Java application. I can single-step, step-over, step-out, break, set breakpoints etc., but I cannot find a way to manually set the next instruction/statement to be executed or alter the execution flow.

An example of this feature is Visual Studio's "Set next statement" under the DEBUG menu.  Another example is MSDOS's g =address where you can specify the next instruction to be executed.

Does the Android Studio Debugger provide a means to change or specify the execution point of the target application?

Comment: You may be looking for a feature called Instant Run and is still in preview for Android Studio 2.0. See: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

Comment: Instant Run is more like an incremental compile feature as best I can tell.  It allows you to switchout modules dynamically which is kool but not the same as modifying the instruction flow.  For example, in the case of an if-else statement, I would like to ignore the results of the if condition and select the block of code to be executed manually.

Comment: Realized what you were looking for later. I believe not possible in Java (and ergo Android) based on this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651379/moving-the-instruction-pointer-while-debugging-java-in-eclipse

Comment: You are right.  This post refers to the same issue/feature.  And the comments on that post are also relevant.  So I guess the answer to my question is NO.  Anyone who is reading this post might want to review the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651379/moving-the-instruction-pointer-while-debugging-java-in-eclipse.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not possible, I usually workaround in the case of simple blocks of code that I might want (or not) to jump.

First you catch the block in a `if` statement:

```
       int foo = bar.toFoo();
       ...
       boolean doThis = Boolean.TRUE;
(B)    if (doThis) {
          ...
          // stuff that I might want to jump
          ...
       }
```

Here (B) is a breakpoint. Now when it is reached, I just click **Evaluate expression** and, if needed, evaluate `doThis = false;`.

One might argue that a decent compiler should get rid of `doThis`, but it actually works in Android Studio 1.5, probably thanks to `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true`.

If willing to, **Evaluate expression** will also let you execute full blocks of code while stuck at the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: The short answer to this question is NO.  You cannot modify the execution point freely as with other programs.  This answer at least provides a method of allowing a manual change in execution flow at a specific breakpoint.